# git push branch without merge

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, git-push

I have one branch master on the server (remote). I created new local branch that doesn't exist on the remote (server). How can I add (push) the branch to the remote (server) without merging it with the master branch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
git push remote local_branch_name:remote_branch_name
```

Usually your remote will be origin, and both local and remote branch will be the same (although you can push local branch as a remote with different name). If their names are identical you don't have to provide colon-separated names -- one will be sufficient.

What you are trying to achieve has nothing to do with merging branches. I'd suggest further reading about branches and remotes ([git-scm book](http://git-scm.com/book) is pretty good resource).

Comment: I already started reading the book, but I needed this urgently. This is just what I've been looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following command:

```
git push -u origin newBranch
```

`-u` will set up your local branch to track the remote branch.

Answer (score 1):

You just push your local branch:

```
$ git push origin <your-branch>
```

You can use the `-u` flag to set your local brach to track the remote too.